# What happens when I use the wrong format specifier?

Tags: c, format-specifiers

Just wondering what happens when I use the wrong format specifier in C?

For example:

```
x = 'A';
printf("%c\n", x);
printf("%d\n", x);

x = 65;
printf("%c\n", x);
printf("%d\n", x);

x = 128;
printf("%d\n", x);
```

Comment: Why don't you try it and... _C_

Comment: Ugh, don't abuse the fact that we can't down-vote comments. :)

Comment: Note that in this specific case,you aren't using a wrong format specifier...

Comment: Without a declaration for `x` this is impossible to answer.

Comment: @MattBall That's rarely the proper answer for a C question.

Comment: @FUZxxl I C that you don't appreciate my terrible puns.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What can happen if printf is called with a wrong format string?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14504148/what-can-happen-if-printf-is-called-with-a-wrong-format-string)

Comment: Why do you think it is wrong? `%c` and `%d` are both expecting a `int`, `'A'`, `65` and `128` are all `int` (note, this is different in C++). If you declared `x` as `int`, then everything is valid.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

> what happens when I use the wrong format specifier in C?

Generally speaking, undefined behaviour.<sup>*</sup>

However, recall that `printf` is a variadic function, and that the arguments to variadic functions undergo the *default argument promotions*.  So for instance, a `char` is promoted to an `int`.  So in practice, these will both give the same results:

```
char x = 'A';
printf("%c\n", x);

int y = 'A';
printf("%c\n", y);
```

whereas this is undefined behaviour:

```
long z = 'A';
printf("%c\n", z);
```

---

<sub>* See for example section 7.19.6.1 p9 of the C99 standard:</sub>

> If any argument is
>   not the correct type for the corresponding conversion specification, the behavior is
>   undefined.

Comment: Yes, undefined behavior as per C11 7.21.6.1 p9.

Comment: By the way, I don't see any wrong formatting specifiers in OPs code assuming `x` has type `int`.

Answer (score -3):

since x is A, the first print f will print: 'A'.

The  second will print the ascii value of A (look it up).

The 3rd one will print the ascii character for 65 (I think this is A or a, but its a letter).

The fourth one will print 65.

The 5th one will print 128.

Comment: The behaviour will **completely** depend on type of `x` (which is not specified in the question itself).