# Unexpected output of printf

Tags: c, casting, printf, garbage

```
int a=5;
float b=3.5;
printf("%d",b);
printf("\n%f",a);
```

Can anyone please tell me why this code is showing unexpected output (garbage\n3.5)

Comment: Didn't your compiler warn you?  `warning: format ‘%d’ expects type ‘int’, but argument 2 has type ‘double’`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What happens when I use the wrong format specifier?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16864552/what-happens-when-i-use-the-wrong-format-specifier)

Answer (score 4):

You are passing a `float` for the `%d` format string, but `printf` is expecting an `int`.

`printf` is a variable argument list function: `printf(const char *format_string,...);`

This means that the rest of the arguments after the format string can be of any type and number, and the compiler doesn't know what they should be.  It is up to the programmer to provide arguments that are of the type that `printf` is expecting.  What `printf` expects is determined by the format string.  When  you give a `%d` in your format string, the printf function is going to expect that the next argument is an `int`.  Since you are passing a `float`, something strange is probably going to happen.  For example, those bytes which make up the floating point number might be treated as if they were an `int`, which won't give you any meaningful value.

Actually it is a little more complicated than that.  There are special rules about how parameters are passed to variable argument functions.  One of the rules is that `float` values are passed as `double`s.  Which means that your `float` value is first converted to a `double` before being passed to `printf`.  Most likely a `double` is eight bytes on your platform, while an `int` is only four.  So the `printf` function could be treating the first four bytes of your `double` value as an `int`.

What is perhaps even worse is that on the next line, an `int` is being passed where a `double` is expected.  Which means that the `printf` function could treat the first four bytes of your `int` as part of the `double`, and then read four more bytes that weren't even part of your arguments.

The details of what actually happens is platform-specific.  The language simply states that you shouldn't pass the wrong type of arguments and makes no guarantees about will happen if you do.

Comment: “those bytes which make up the floating point number are going to be treated as if they were an int” This may be what happens, or something else. Many platforms have specialized registers for floating-point values and integers, and the ABI may say that the first integer argument goes in one and the first floating-point argument goes in the other. Then what `printf()` shows is not the bytes of a `double` interpreted as integer, it is the contents of a register that did not even know it was going to be printed. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions

Comment: @PascalCuoq: I've updated my wording to reflect that this is only an example of what might happen.

Answer (score 4):

Format string incorrect error, according to your declarations of `a` and `b`:

```
printf("%d",b); <-- "b is float"     Wrong!
printf("\n%f",a); <-- "a is an int"   Wrong! -- Undefined behavior
```

should be:

```
printf("%f",b);
printf("\n%d",a);
```

> **Q  :-**  Why you getting that output?

It's due to undefined behavior of your code:

From [INTERNATIONAL STANDARD ©ISO/IEC ISO/IEC 9899:201x](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf)

> ### 7.16.1 Variable argument list access macros
>
> (page 270)
>
> #### 7.16.1.1 The `va_arg` macro
>
> [...] If there is no actual next argument, or if type is not compatible with
>   the type of the actual next argument (as promoted according to the
>   default argument promotions), the `behavior is undeﬁned`, except for the following cases:
>    — one type is a `signed integer type`, the other type is the
>   corresponding `unsigned integer`  type, and the value is representable
>   in both types;
>   — one type is pointer to `void` and the other is a
>   pointer to a character type

Answer (score 1):

Because the `a` variable is a int type, while your are specifying a format string for a  float type, and vice versa for the variable `b`.

Note :

`%d` is for **integer** type

`%f` is for **float**  type

You should use :

```
int a=5;
float b=3.5;
printf("%f",b);
printf("\n%d",a);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
int main()
{

int a=5;
float b=3.5;
printf("%f",b); //Use %f
printf("\n%d",a); // Use %d

}
```

Refer: [printf](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/)

wrong format specifier to `printf` leads undefined behavior in most cases.

However, since `printf` is a variadic function, and the arguments to variadic 
functions undergo the default argument cast. 
Like, a char is casted to an int.