# Issue with floating point representation

Tags: c, casting, floating-point

Consider:

```
int x = 25, i; 
float *p = (float *)&x;
printf("%f\n", *p);
```

I understand that bit representation for floating point numbers and int are different, but no matter what value I store, the answer is always 0.000000. Shouldn't it be some other value depending on the floating point representation?

Comment: Read about [_undefined behaviour_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behaviour).

Comment: Why don't you try it in the other direction to see how a small floatimg point number is represented. (And/Or do some research at Wikipedia.)

Comment: The value is 0.000000000000000000000000000000000000000000035, which displays as 0.000000 because you used the %f format. You can use [this web site](http://www.h-schmidt.net/FloatConverter/IEEE754.html) to try out other values.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it seeks to explain UB.

Comment: Also, it's a multi-dup, and was asked recently at least once. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17898186/unexpected-output-of-printf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the purposes of this discussion, we're going to assume both `int` and `float` are 32 bits wide.  We're also going to assume IEEE-754 floats.

Floating point values are represented as `sign * βexp * signficand`.  For 32-bit binary floats, `β` is `2`, the exponent *`exp`* ranges from `-126` to `127`, and the *significand* is a *normalized* binary fraction, such that there is a single leading non-zero bit before the radix point.  For example, the binary integer representation of `25` is

`110012`

while the binary floating point representation of `25.0` would be:

```
1.10012 * 24 // normalized
```

The IEEE-754 encoding for a 32-bit float is

```
s eeeeeeee fffffffffffffffffffffff
```

where `s` denotes the sign bit, `e` denotes the exponent bits, and `f` denotes the significand (fraction) bits.  The exponent is encoded using "excess 127" notation, meaning an exponent value of `127` (`011111112`) represents `0`, while `1` (`000000012`) represents `-126` and `254` (`111111102`) represents `127`.  The leading bit of the significand is not explicitly stored, so `25.0` would be encoded as

```
0 10000011 10010000000000000000000 // exponent 131-127 = 4
```

However, what happens when you map the *bit pattern* for the 32-bit *integer* value `25` onto a 32-bit floating point format?  We wind up with the following:

```
0 00000000 00000000000000000011001
```

It turns out that in IEEE-754 floats, exponent value `000000002` is reserved for representing `0.0` and *subnormal* (or denormal) numbers.  A subnormal number is number close to `0` that can't be represented as `1.??? * 2exp`, because the exponent would have to be smaller than what we can encode in 8 bits.  Such numbers are interpreted as `0.??? * 2-126`, with as many leading `0`s as necessary.

In this case, it adds up to `0.000000000000000000110012 * 2-126`, which gives us `3.50325 * 10-44`.

You'll have to map large integer values (in excess of `224`) to see anything other than 0 out to a bunch of decimal places.  And, like Keith says, this is all undefined behavior anyway.

Answer (score 6):

Your code has undefined behavior -- but it will most likely behave as you expect, as long as the size and alignment of types `int` and `float` are compatible.

By using the "%f" format to print `*p`, you're losing a lot of information.

Try this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void) {
        int x = 25; 
        float *p = (float*)&x;
        printf("%g\n", *p);
        return 0;
}
```

On my system (and probably on yours), it prints:

```
3.50325e-44
```

The `int` value `25` has zeros in most of its high-order bits. Those bits are probably in the same place as the exponent field of type `float` -- resulting in a very small number.

Look up IEEE floating-point representation for more information. Byte order is going to be an issue. (And don't do this kind of thing in real code unless you have a *very* good reason.)

As rici suggests in a comment, a better way to learn about floating-point representation is to start with a floating-point value, convert it to an unsigned integer of the same size, and display the integer value in hexadecimal. For example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void show(float f) {
    unsigned int rep;
    memcpy(&rep, &f, sizeof rep);
    printf("%g --> 0x%08x\n", f, rep);
}


int main(void) {
    if (sizeof (float) != sizeof (unsigned int)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Size mismatch\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    show(0.0);
    show(1.0);
    show(1.0/3.0);
    show(-12.34e5);
    return 0;
}
```