# How to make uninitiated pointer not equal to 0/null?

Tags: c++, pointers

I am a c++ learner. Others told me "uninitiatied pointer may point to anywhere". How to prove that by code.?I made a little test code but my uninitiatied pointer always point to 0. In which case it does not point to 0? Thanks

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    int* p;
    printf("%d\n", p);
    char* p1;
    printf("%d\n", p1);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It depends on your system and compiler, understand, that "anywhere" includes `null` too, so you already proved it.

Comment: Accessing the value of an uninitialized variable is undefined behavior. Here you are printing the value of `p`, which can do anything it wants at this point.

Comment: I guess it should be rephrased as "uninitiatied pointer does not point anywhere"

Comment: [to print pointer use `%p`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9053658/995714). [Using the wrong format specifier invokes undefined behavior](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16864552/995714). And why do you `#include <iostream>` but then use `printf`? Using a function without declaration is undefined behavior too

Comment: [What Every C Programmer Should Know About Undefined Behavior](http://blog.llvm.org/2011/05/what-every-c-programmer-should-know.html)

Comment: Your code has a bug -- you try to print the value of `p` before you assign it a value. Fix the bug and the mystery will go away.

Comment: Old MSVC compilers (I think I've last tried it in like 2008) did zero-initialize all memory areas when compiling **Debug** code. I would really be suprised if it weren't still the case, so I guess, your first task is trying to compile your code in **Release** mode. _note:_ I have compiled C/C++ code under Linux systems, but in a preconfigured environment and I did much less experimenting, so I don't know if they have the same behaviour.

Comment: "How to prove that": quote the standard.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Any uninitialized variable by definition has an indeterminate value until a value is supplied, and even accessing it is undefined. Because this is the grey-area of *undefined behaviour*, there's no way you can guarantee that an uninitialized pointer will be anything other than `0`.

Anything you write to demonstrate this would be dictated by the compiler and system you are running on.

If you really want to, you can try writing a function that fills up a local array with garbage values, and create another function that defines an uninitialized pointer and prints it. Run the second function after the first in your `main()` and you might see it.

**Edit:** For you curiosity, I exhibited the behavior with VS2015 on my system with this code:

```
void f1()
{
  // junk
  char arr[24];
  for (char& c : arr) c = 1;
}

void f2()
{
  // uninitialized
  int* ptr[4];
  std::cout << (std::uintptr_t)ptr[1] << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
  f1();
  f2();
  return 0;
}
```

Which prints `16843009` (`0x01010101`). But again, this is all *undefined behaviour*.

Comment: _Out of plain curiosity:_ Did you compile using **debug** or **release** settings? _(Old MSVS used to zero-initialize memory areas in **debug** builds, which caused heisenbugs in the old days.)_

Comment: this was in release mode, in debug mode I get `3435973836`, which is `0xCCCCCCCC`

Comment: Nice! Looks like somewhere in the way Microsoft have introduced an "uninitialized pointer" constant.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I think it is not worth to prove this question, because a good coding style should be used and this say's: Initialise all variables! One example: If you "free" a pointer, just give them a value like in this example:

```
char *p=NULL;          // yes, this is not needed but do it! later you may change your program an add code beneath this line...
p=(char *)malloc(512);
...
free(p);
p=NULL;
```

That is a safe and good style. Also if you use `free(p)` again by accident, it will not crash your program ! In this example - if you don't set `NULL` to `p` after doing a `free()`, your can use the pointer by mistake again and your program would try to address already freed memory - this will crash your program or (more bad) may end in strange results.
So don't waste time on you question about a case where pointers do not point to `NULL`. Just set values to your variables (pointers) ! :-)

Comment: `malloc()` and `free()` with c++?

Comment: The bigger problem IMO: why is there a naked pointer outside a class? When `free(this->p)` is in a destructor, there won't be a `p` left that needs to be set to `nullptr`.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the compiler. Your code executed on an old MSVC2008 displays in release mode (plain random):

```
1955116784
1955116784
```

and in debug mode (after croaking for using unitialized pointer usage):

```
-858993460
-858993460
```

because that implementation sets uninitialized pointers to 0xcccccccc in debug mode to detect their usage.

The standard says that *using an uninitialized pointer* leads to *undefined behaviour*. That means that *from the standard* anything can happen. But a particular implementation is free to do whatever it wants:

- yours happen to set the pointers to 0 (but you should not rely on it unless it is documented in the implementation documentation)
- MSVC in debug mode sets the pointer to 0xcccccccc in debug mode but AFAIK does not document it (*), so we still cannot rely on it

(*) at least I could not find any reference...