# Casting double to int in C

Tags: c, casting, int, double

When I cast the double value **44.000000** to int, I get the desired value of **44**.

But, When cast the same double value (**44.000000**) that was derived by *some arithmetic operations* to int, I get **43**.

How can I get rid of this problem and get *44 instead of 43* in the second case?

Below is the code I used,

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>

int main(){

    double newd = 44.00;
    printf("Simple Direct Conversion: %d\n\n", (int)newd);

    double d = 100.44;
    double decPart;
    double fracPart = modf(d, &decPart);

    printf("Original Values:      %lf - %lf\n", decPart, fracPart);
    printf("Multiplied by 100:    %lf - %lf\n", decPart * 100, fracPart * 100);
    printf("Converted to Integer: %d - %d\n", (int)(decPart * 100), (int)(fracPart * 100));

    return 0;
}
```

and the output is,

> Simple Direct Conversion: 44
>
> Original Values:      100.000000 - 0.440000
>
> Multiplied by 100:    10000.000000 - 44.000000
>
> Converted to Integer: 10000 - 43

Comment: 0.44*100 is not 44 [Is floating point math broken?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/588004/995714)

Comment: That means your calculation is coming out in the form of 43.xx even if it's 43.99 it will print 43 .go with the calculation and check where you are going wrong. fracPart value

Comment: to print `int` use `%d`. [Using the wrong format specifier invokes undefined behavior](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16864552/995714)

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc, I get same answer with %d. This is not duplicate. I need explicit answer to get 44.

Comment: the fact that it works in your case doesn't mean that's not undefined behavior. Any thing can happen. [What Every C Programmer Should Know About Undefined Behavior](http://blog.llvm.org/2011/05/what-every-c-programmer-should-know.html)

Comment: So, what are the other possible methods to get 44? any workarounds in case if have?

Comment: I fixed myself,

    printf("Expected Value:       %d - %d\n", (int)(round(decPart * 100)), (int)round(fracPart * 100));