# Why does printf and cout gives different output for this unsigned int?

Tags: c++

When I printed value of **b** using two of ways, I though it should be the same output on the console, but it didn't.

```
unsigned int b = -1000;
std::cout << b << std::endl;
printf("%d\n",b);
```

**Output:**

cout:   `4294966296`
printf: `-1000`

The correct value of **b** should be around *0 -> 4294967296*. **The output of cout is correctly**. However, I did not understand why the **printf** **keeping wrong value?**

Can anyone explain to me ?

Comment: you're printing `unsigned int` with `%d` which invokes undefined behavior. In most implementations it'll simply treat the bit patterns in the unsigned as signed

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16864552/what-happens-when-i-use-the-wrong-format-specifier It's not same my issue. It's talking about wrong format specifier it was not explained why cout and printf have different output.

Comment: cout is using the correct type of the variable so obviously it'll print an unsigned value]

Comment: Thank Phuc. I understood now, just because I was using wrong format specifier.

Answer (score 2):

You're telling `printf` to print a *signed* int value with the `%d` format specifier.  Technically undefined behavior, but most implementations will convert the unsigned value back to the equivalent signed value to print.

You want `%u` to print an unsigned value.

Comment: Thank Chris. I understood now, just because I was using wrong format specifier.

Answer (score 1):

`printf("%d\n",b);` prints a signed number due to the `%d` flag. If you want an unsigned number use `%u`:

```
printf("%u\n",b);
```

Comment: Thanks atom, I understood now.