# What do these errors mean in C?

Tags: c

I'm doing a college assignment in C. We have to write a simple programme that just creates different data types (ints, longs, doubles) and prints them out and their size using the sizeof() function. This is the code I have written for the function that creates an int:

```
void createInt(){
int i = 3;
printf(int i);
printf(sizeof(int i));
}
```

It's giving the following errors:
For "printf(int i);" it's giving: **warning C4047: 'function': 'const char *const ' differs in levels of indirection from 'int'**
For "printf(sizeof(int i));" it's giving: **warning C4024: 'printf': different types for formal and actual parameter 1**

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I'm completely new to C. Have never used it before. 
Thanks!

Comment: You should go back and re-read your book on C because that is definitely not how you use `printf`

Comment: @Tyler they do need to specify the format string though

Comment: Welcome to C ! You should use `man` if you need to understand a function, in this case you have to search the man of [printf](https://linux.die.net/man/3/printf)

Answer (score 1):

What the error means is that you're passing the wrong type of parameter to the function printf. It was declared to take a `const char *` as its first parameter. You're passing it an `int` then a `size_t`.

When `printf` takes only one parameter, that parameter **must** be a string. But if you want to print the content of the integer `i` use `printf("%d", i)` or the value of `sizeof(i)` which is of the type `size_t` use it like this : `printf("%zu%, sizeof(i))`

Answer (score -2):

`printf` needs a string as its first parameter. What you mean to do is

```
printf("%i\n", i);
printf("%zu\n", sizeof i);
```

Comment: did you mean `%d` ?

Comment: Use `%zu` instead of `%i` for result of `sizeof`.

Comment: nit: `sizeof i` is probably better style, as it indicates that sizeof is not a runtime function.  But this is purely a stylistic point.

Comment: @KiJéy using either %d or %i is a bad idea. [`size_t` are supposed to be printed by `%zu`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/940087/995714). Using the [wrong format specifier invokes undefined behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16864552/995714)

Comment: Yes I meant that for the int `i`, I didn't know the existence of `%i` and I still don't know what's the difference between `%i` and `%d`