# void*,pointers of strings and characters

Tags: c, pointers, void-pointers

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
void main() 
{
   char cr[] = "Yash";
   clrscr();
   printf("%p\n",(void*)cr);
   printf("%p\n",cr);
   printf("%p\n",&cr);
   printf("%p\n",&cr[0]);
   printf("%p\n",cr[0]);
   printf("%p\n",(void*)cr[0]);

   printf("%c\n",&cr[0]);
   printf("%s\n",&cr);
   printf("%c\n",(void*)cr[0]);
   printf("%s\n",(void*)cr);
   getch();
}
```

Output:

```
FFEE
FFEE
FFEE
FFEE
0059
0059
ε
Yash
Y
Yash
```

**Question:**
I fail to understand exactly the output which I get in this code. Can somebody please explain each output why is it the way it is. Especially why does `printf("%c",&cr[0]);` give some sought of `ε` this weird or may be be null symbol?
 And why are outputs of `(void*)cr[0]` and `cr[0]` different from the other 3 in the half of `%p`? If they are just addresses then why different?(I am really really sorry for the last minute changes I made:/)

Comment: 0059 isn't an address, it's the value in hex of the character 'Y'.

Comment: In short: Undefined behavior. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16864552/what-happens-when-i-use-the-wrong-format-specifier

Comment: Using %p for something else than a pointer is UB.

Comment: OT: Since the code have undefined behavior, the output doesn't need to make any sense at all. In the real world the output often makes some kind of sense. Looking at your code and the output, I'm wondering whether the output is really from executing the posted code. Is it or did you do some last minute changes?

Comment: Is that 16 bit Turbo C?

Comment: @MichaelWalz Doesn't %p require not just a pointer but a void pointer?

Comment: Yes,Its TurboC3

Comment: `printf("%s",&cr);` --> `printf` expects `&cr` to be a valid pointer  to a _string_.  It is not.  Results: _undefined behavior_ - anything may occur.

Comment: @4386427 you're right

Comment: I can't understand why people still use this crappy antique piece of software. Turbo C was great 25 years ago when the average PC had 4 Mb of memory, but today there are better (and also free) alternatives.

Comment: @MichaelWalz If one is using a 25 year old computer, Turbo C makes sense.  Ask the OP what computer they are using.  Agree about many good alternatives,

Comment: @chux good point, but if he is able to use a modern web site such as stackoverflow, his computer is most likely not that old.

Comment: Yeah I know Turbo C is really a very crappy software, I have already switched to code blocks but i just wanted to understand all about void*,*,& etc in C. That is why this code and I wish to know the reason behind each output if someone could help OR some really good link for understanding the same.I am once again sorry for the last minute changes.

Answer (score 3):

> explain each output

UB is *undefined behavior*: **Anything** may happen. 
`"%p"` expects a `void*`.  pointers to characters and `void*` have same representation.

```
char cr[] = "Yash";
printf("%p\n",(void*)cr);     // OK:  address of CR[0]
printf("%p\n",cr);            // OK:  address of CR[0]  
printf("%p\n",&cr);           // UB,  &cr is neither a void * or pointer to a character
printf("%p\n",&cr[0]);        // OK:  address of CR[0]  
printf("%p\n",cr[0]);         // UB   cr[0] is neither a void * or pointer to a character
printf("%p\n",(void*)cr[0]);  // UB,  conversion to void* from arbitrary integer
```

`"%s"` expects a `char*` to a valid *string*

```
printf("%s\n",&cr);           // UB,  Not a `char *`
printf("%s\n",(void*)cr);     // OK
```

`"%c"` expects a `int`, converts that to a `unsigned char` and prints that character.

```
printf("%c\n",&cr[0]);        // UB, pointer passed as int
printf("%c\n",(void*)cr[0]);  // UB, pointer passed as int
```

> why does `printf("%s",&cr);` give ....

`printf("%s",&cr);` --> `printf` expects `&cr` to be a valid pointer  to a *string*.  It is not.  Results: *undefined behavior* - anything may occur.

> why are outputs of (void*)cr[0] and cr[0] different from the other 3 in the half of "%p

`printf("%p\n",(void*)cr[0]);` and `printf("%p\n",cr[0]);` are UB.

---

Explaining output when UB occurs is not productive until one clearly understands why explaining UB is not generally useful.

Comment: "why does printf("%c",&cr[0]); give some sought of ...". As all ready answered, it is [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).  Anything may happen,  You seem to want to still want know why this _undefined behavior_ results in an `ε`.  There are numerous possible explanations including the address had a byte in it corresponding to the character `ε`.  Yet this is not a efficient use of time.  One needs to know not to code `printf("%c",&cr[0]);` in the first place and 2nd, use a compiler that provides warnings to such trivial coding mistakes.

Comment: I wrote the program to understand the concept. That's it!But I agree with compiler thing as I should use Codeblocks or something.