# float f = 1.25 's hex value in visual studio 2017, win 10

Tags: c++, visual-studio, hex, decimal

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    float f = 1.25; // set a breakpoint in the left!

    cout << " hex value=" << hex << f << endl;
    printf("%x", f);
    return 0;
}
```

With a breakpoint in that line, press F5 to debug, it shows the value is '-107374176.' , how does this number concluded? 
[image]

If I run without debug, the results in console is
[image: result in console]

These two numbers also confused me a lot.

Comment: It is some garbage value. `1.25` has not been assigned to `f` yet. Do one "Step Over" and then check `f`. And don't use inconsistent formats in `printf`.

Comment: %x is not for printing floats. [Using the wrong format specifier invokes UB](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16864552/995714)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Evg and @ phuclv, I know how the number '-107374176.' appears.

With that breakpoint, 1.25 is not assigned to f, then the value of f is (cccccccc) in hex,

(cccccccc)hex = (‭1 10011001 10011001100110011001100‬)bin

(10011001)bin = (153)dec, 153 - 127 = 26

(1.10011001100110011001100) = (1.5999999046325684)dec

so (‭1 10011001 10011001100110011001100‬)bin = (-1.5999999046325684 * 2^26)dec

= (107374176.0000000027262976)dec

Answer (score 1):

Putting a breakpoint at that line does not mean that particular line has been evaluated / executed yet. Previous statements (above the breakpoint) have been executed, but that one has yet to be executed. Variable `f` has not been initialized at that point so you are seeing some random garbage in memory. Press  <kbd>F10</kbd> to step over that line and observe the different results.

One possible workflow could be:

- Press <kbd>F9</kbd> to set a breakpoint in your code
- Press <kbd>F5</kbd> to start debugging
- Keep pressing <kbd>F10</kbd> to
  step through your code one line at the time