# Atoll values for negative numbers in C

Tags: c, atoi

I'm trying to use atoll to convert a string of numbers with spaces. I want to make a loop in C that will only take positive numbers.

So far, from what I understand, atoll on a char would return 0, likewise with a combination of an int and char, such as "3a". However, is there a range of values for negative numbers for atoll on a negative number?

I found that the result of -1 is 18446744073709551615, -2 is 18446744073709551614, -3 is 18446744073709551613, etc, based on my first print statement.

```
for(arg = 1; arg < argc; ++arg)
{
   printf("%llu\n", atoll(argv[arg]));

   if(atoll(argv[arg]) == 0 || atoll(argv[arg]) >= xxxxx))
   {
     printf("Enter a valid number.");
   }
   else
   {
     printf("irrelevant code here");
   }
}
```

Comment: This shouldn't compile. `atoll(x >= y)` is not a valid call. Do you mean `atoll(x) >= y`?

Comment: Are your valid input numbers guaranteed to lie in some range?

Comment: @tadman yes, sorry. in that case, y is to be where the lower bound of negative numbers atoll would be.

Comment: "I found that..."  Those results are not correct, but some incorrect ways of printing or comparing numbers might make it seem like they are.  Please paste a [mcve] showing why you thought that was happening.

Comment: @alex I wanted positive numbers only for this loop.

Comment: @aschepler kindly view update

Comment: If you're working with *unsigned* values you can't even talk about negative numbers, they don't exist.  If you're talking about signed values you can deal with negative values, but `%llu` is explicitly unsigned. Use `%lld` in that case.

Comment: @tadman Oh I see, that makes sense now. In that case, what was the print `%llu` statement  representing with that output?

Comment: It was converting to unsigned which for negative values exposes [Two's Complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two's_complement).

Comment: 18446744073709551615 is 2^64 - 1.  Look up "two's complement arithmetic".

Comment: [using the wrong format specifier invokes UB](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16864552/995714). And [don't use `atoll`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17710018/995714)

Comment: Jamie L., A subtle important aspect of this coding goal is "Is the value of xxxxx representable in the long long range?"  If xxxxx is larger than `LONG_MAX`, than the problem becomes  harder .  There is more at play than just a mis-match printf specifier.  What is the type of xxxxx and its potential maximum value?

Answer (score 1):

From your code fragment it is not possible to figure out several important things. Did you include correct headers, did you use correct format specifiers and length modifiers in printf? In example bellow you can find correct includes an correct format for long long.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    printf("%lld\n", atoll("-1"));
    return 0;
}
```

/* this example prints correct output of -1 */

Comment: Actually, it was because I was using `%llu`, so it was printing output that I expected from `%lld` instead.