# What if i try to print large ints using %c and %s?

Tags: c, string, character

If i try to print 1000 as given in C:

```
printf("%c\n",1000);
printf("%s\n",1000);
```

What will be the output?Or Will I get error for both lines ?

Comment: Why don't you just run the code to see what happens?

Comment: @B001ᛦ It shows segmentation fault

Comment: @B001ᛦ: Trying code on one C implementation only shows what one C implementation does in the particular circumstances tested. It does not explain the semantics or other rules defined by the C standard.

Answer (score 4):

```
printf("%c\n",1000);
```

`%c` requires an argument of type `int` (so far, so good) and prints it as a character. 1000 is (almost certainly) outside the range of `char` or `unsigned char`, but

> If no `l` length modifier is present, the `int` argument is converted
>   to an `unsigned char`, and the resulting character is written.

Conversion to an unsigned integer type is well defined; it's reduced modulo `UCHAR_MAX+1`. Assuming `UCHAR_MAX==255` (which it almost certainly is) the result of the conversion is `(unsigned char)232`, so it will (attempt to) print character 232. The result is likely to depend on the locale. You're likely to run into problems with 232 (0xe8) being an invalid UTF-8 encoding.

```
printf("%s\n",1000);
```

`%s` requires an argument of type `char*`. so the behavior is undefined. (What's likely to happen in practice is that the value `1000` is treated as if it were a pointer. It's unlikely that that's a valid address, or that there's a valid string starting at that address.)

Answer (score 2):

Using the wrong format specifier for printf invokes undefined behavior bugs, meaning that anything can happen. Pondering about why you get a certain kind of undefined behavior won't give you much in the way of meaningful knowledge, but anyway...

In the case `printf("%s\n",1000);` you simply lie to the compiler and tell it that `1000` is a pointer to an allocated string of characters. It's hard to tell exactly what will happen - maybe the compiler will run off to address 1000 and attempt to access it, possibly resulting in a crash.

In the case of `printf("%c\n",1000);` this is actually somewhat deterministic behavior, by accident. All arguments to variadic functions like printf get implicitly promoted. Had you passed a `char`, it would have been promoted to `int` and then converted back to `char`.

But you pass the integer constant `1000` which is of type `int`. As it happens, `printf` expects an `int` after the implicit promotion and it will try to convert `1000` "back" to a `char`. This means that the compiler will grab the least significant byte of the `int` and treat that as `char` (or to be picky, as `unsigned char`).

`1000` == `0x000003E8`. The `char` conversion will grab the least significant `E8` byte. And then print whatever that character represents in the symbol table, if anything.

Comment: I don't think the behaviour is undefined. It does exactly what you say, it tries to access the address 1000. I think this is well defined

Comment: @RoQuOTriX in the case of `printf("%s\n",1000);` if pointers are 64-bit and `int` is 32-bit, only 4 bytes will be pushed onto the stack. The `printf` function however expects to find an 8 byte pointer, and the content of the other 4 bytes is unknown.

Comment: @RoQuOTriX The behaviour is undefined if the wrong format specifier is used. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16864552/what-happens-when-i-use-the-wrong-format-specifier

Comment: @EricPostpischil Fixed. I hadn't checked what printf says about `%c` in detail, and it does say that there is an implicit conversion from `int` to `unsigned char`. In which case endianess does indeed not matter.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to the printf format specifiers: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/

`%c` - used to print a character (`char`), which normally has a value between -128 to 127 (it can also be 0 to 255)

`%s` - used to print an array of `char`s with the last char as `NULL` (`\0`)

So `printf("%c\n",1000);` exhibits implementation defined behaviour as 1000 is greater than 128 (or 255).

and `printf("%s\n",1000);` is trying to print an array of chars located at address 1000 (which is most likely wrong). It is also undefined behaviour, so anything could happen.

If you are trying to print an integer you should use `%d`, like such:

```
printf("%d\n",1000);
```

Comment: `printf("%c\n",1000);` doesn't have undefined behavior. The `int` argument is converted to `unsigned char`. See my answer.

Comment: @KeithThompson Agree. I should better say it is implementation defined.

Comment: Also, `char` doesn't necessarily have the range 0-255. On desktop systems, -128 to 127 is most common.

Comment: @Lundin Yes indeed. That's why I said 'normally'. I fixed the answer accordingly.

Comment: @Lundin: The signedness of plain `char` is irrelevant in this case. The standard specifically says the `int` argument is converted to `unsigned char`, which has a range of 0..255 *unless* you're on some exotic system (most likely a DSP) with `CHAR_BIT > 8`. Also, out-of-range integer conversion to an unsigned type is well defined, unlike out-of-range integer conversion to a signed type.

Comment: @KeithThompson It is not irrelevant if the passed character is negative, then sign extended during promotion to `int`. What value that will get printed depends on the signedness format of `char`, regardless of the conversion to `unsigned char` later on.

Comment: @Lundin It's irrelevant to the code in the question, which passes the `int` value 1000. Do you have an example where it does matter?

Comment: @Lundin If you have a signed char and promote it to an int, surely you'll have sign extension. In this case printf demotes the int (1000) to an unsigned char, which involves no sign extension. So the signedness is irrelevant as KeithThompson says, or am I missing something? See section 7.19.6.1 point 8 of C99.