# scanf integer with %ld %ld is not work correctly

Tags: c, gcc, scanf, undefined-behavior

I'm using gcc 4.4.7.

When I run below simple logic(C lang).

Then inputted '1 2'.

```
 int var1 = 0; 
 int var2 = 0;

 if(!scanf("%ld %ld",&var1, &var2))
 {
    printf("--- ERROR\n");
 }
 else
 {
    printf("--- var1  [%ld] \n", var1);
    printf("--- var2  [%ld] \n", var2);
 }
```

Result :
--- var1 [0] 
--- var2 [2]

**I already know %ld works for long int. What I realy want to know is how does scanf working in detail.**
This happens when I try to scan 2 or more numbers.

Comment: `int` is not a `long`.  Change declaration to `long int var1`, etc.

Comment: I already know how to figure out this one. I wonder the reason why var2 assigned correctly but var1 does not.

Comment: This is because you should use `%d` format to match `int`. Also, please don't check the return value from `scanf` with `!` but with the number of conversions expected: `if(scanf("%d %d", &var1, &var2) != 2)`

Comment: @WeatherVane Could you explain more detail?
If just incorrect then, both of them should not be assigned. But it's not.

Comment: @HyunyoungGo that leads to [Undefined Behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16864552/what-happens-when-i-use-the-wrong-format-specifier), please see my answer, where I merged Weather Vane's and Mark Ronson's comment.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The format specifier `%ld` is for `long int` (and `%lld` for `long long int`).

`int` should be matched with the `%d` format specifier.  Using a format specifier that does *not* agree with the variable types leads to **Undefined Behavior.**

Don't check the return value from scanf with the `!` operator but with the number of conversions expected instead, like this:

```
if(scanf("%d %d", &var1, &var2) != 2)
  printf("--- ERROR\n");
```

**Further Reading**
[What happens when I use the wrong format specifier?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16864552/what-happens-when-i-use-the-wrong-format-specifier)

Comment: The key point left unsaid is that using a format that doesn't agree with the variable types leads to undefined behavior. Trying to make sense of anything after that is worthless.

Comment: @R.. even that is subject to change with different compiler versions.  Trying to reason about undefined behavior is a good way to drive yourself crazy.

Comment: @MarkRansom: For exploits you just need to know what your target compiled it with. Which is easy if they're using a mainstream binary distro.