# Why format specifier %d or %i does not work for a double variable but %f works and print a float output of an integer variable?

Tags: c, variables, format, format-specifiers

Must we always use `%f` to printf a `%d` value, and `%lf` to take input by `scanf` ? Why format specifier `%d` or `%i` does not work for a `double` variable but `%f` works and print a float output of an integer variable?
Is it always safe to declare double and take input `scanf` with `%lf` and `printf` as `%f`?

My codes:

```
int main(void)
{

    double dnum = 7777;
    printf(" %f \n", dnum);

        return 0;
}
```

output is 7777.000000

```
int main(void)
{

    double dnum = 7777;
    printf(" %i \n", dnum);

        return 0;
}
```

Output is 0

```
int main(void)
{

    double dnum = 7777;
    printf(" %d \n", dnum);

        return 0;
}
```

Output is 0

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, "why"?  They are defined to expect arguments of different types.

Comment: When you define the variable `dnum` as a `double` it will never contain an integer value. No matter how you initialize it, the value of that `double` variable will always be a `double` precision floating point value.

Comment: The explanation for any particular behavior will depend on your specific platform.  For instance, on some machines, floating point values are passed in one set of registers, and integers are passed in a different set.  In that case your `printf(" %i \n", dnum);` may result in the number 7777.0 being loaded into a floating-point register, but `printf` prints the value from an integer register which contains something totally unrelated.

Comment: The format specifier `%f` in function `printf` is not the format specifier for `float` (there isn't one) but for `double`. A `float` argument passed to variadic function gets promoted to `double` (not to be confused with the way `scanf` works). So your first example is *supposed* to work, and it does. You are passing a `double` value for `%f`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What happens when I use the wrong format specifier?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16864552/what-happens-when-i-use-the-wrong-format-specifier)

Answer (score 1):

Format and data mismatch in `printf()` invokes *undefine behavior*.

In your code, the type of `dnum` is `double` regardless of its actual value, which may be an integer.

`%f` can be used to print `double`, but neithor `%d` nor `%i` cannot be used.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to print `double`, you should use `%g`, `%f` or `%e` depending on the format that you want it to be printed.

`%d` is the same as `%i` (for `printf`) and it goes along with `signed integer`.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome in the world of *undefined behavior*!

To use the `%d` conversion specifier to print a `double` value or the `%f` conversion specifier to print an `int` value invokes [undefined behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2397984/undefined-unspecified-and-implementation-defined-behavior).

`%f` is furthermore meant to print a value of type `double`, not `float`. A passed `float` gets automatically promoted.

The C standard states:

> If a conversion specification is invalid, the behavior is undefined.288) **If any argument is not the correct type for the corresponding conversion specification, the behavior is undefined**.
>
> Source: C18, 7.21.6.1/9

---

> d,i - **The `int` argument** is converted to signed decimal in the style[-]dddd.   The precision specifies the minimum number of digits to appear; if the value being converted can be represented in fewer digits, it is expanded with leading zeros. The default precision is 1. The result of converting a zero value with a precision of zero is no characters.
>
> ......
>
> f,F - **A `double` argument** representing a floating-point number is converted to decimal notation in the style[-]ddd.ddd, where the number of digits after the decimal-point character is equal to the precision specification.  If the precision is missing, it is taken as 6;  if the precision is zero and the flag is not specified, no decimal-point character appears. If a decimal-point character appears, at least one digit appears before it. The value is rounded to the appropriate number of digits.
>
> A double argument representing an infinity is converted in one of the styles[-]infor[-]infinity— which style is implementation-defined. A double argument representing a NaN is converted in one of the styles[-]nanor[-]nan(n-char-sequence)— which style, and the meaning of any n-char-sequence, is implementation-defined. The F conversion specifier produces INF,INFINITY, or NAN instead of inf, infinity, or nan, respectively.283)
>
> Source: C18, §7.21.6.1/8

---

#### Summary:

Except for the first example, The output you get is any arbitrary value (unless the implementation didn't specified what happens else). It doesn't "work" in the one way nor in the other.

Answer (score 1):

The format specifier: `%d` or `%i` expects the argument of `signed int`, if anything else is given in the formatted `printf()` statement, such as:

```
float f = 1.50235F;
printf("%d", f);
```

Will expect for `signed int`, if you pass a `float` or a `double` instead, it'll tend to undefined behavior and probably print `0`.

In a more practical sense, if you want to do-it-yourself, you may add `-Wformat` flag and run the command in your command prompt or any command shell:

```
$ gcc -o main main.cpp -Wformat
```

Then you'll get a warning generated by the compiler similar to the following:

```
main.c: In function 'int main()':
main.c:9:14: warning: format '%d' expects argument of type 'int', but argument 2 has type 'double' [-Wformat=]
    9 |     printf("%d\n", d);
      |             ~^     ~
      |              |     |
      |              int   double
      |             %f
```

The `double` has the twice precision than a `float` could hold (i.e. `double` has 15 decimal digits of precision, while `float` has only 7. So, the `%f` type specifier could be used for `double` in this case too.)

To know further about the format specifiers: [List of all format specifiers in C](https://codeforwin.org/2015/05/list-of-all-format-specifiers-in-c-programming.html).

Answer (score 1):

All conversion specifiers expect their corresponding argument to be a specific type; you can't arbitrarily mix and match them.  `%d` and `%i` expect their corresponding argument to have type `int` - if it doesn't, the behavior is *undefined* and you'll (usually) get weird output.  Integers and floating point values have very different binary representations and may have different sizes - most modern platforms use 32 bits to store integer values and 64 bits to store doubles, which affects how those values are interpreted in the `printf` code.

For an authoritative list of conversion specifiers and the types of arguments they take, refer to the [C 2011 Online Draft](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf), section 7.21.6.1 (The `fprintf` function).