# Why this array takes only 3 elements?

Tags: arrays, c, char

In this array ,the given array is of size 5,but it is not taking more than 3 elements,
Why?

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    char a[10],*q;
    int i;
    q=a;
    for(i=0;i<5;i++) {
        scanf("%c",a+i);//a[5]={a,b,c}
    }
    for(int i=0;i<5;i++) {
        printf("%c",*(a+i));
    }
    printf("\n%d",sizeof(a));
    printf("\n%d",sizeof(q));
}
```

Comment: You're probably pressing ENTER which adds a `'\n'` to `a`.  Are you doing something like: `a`, ENTER, `b`, ENTER, `c`, ENTER?  Try typing: `a`, `b`, `c`, `d`, `e`, ENTER.

Comment: Your array size is 10 (not 5) - your 1st printf should show this.  If you typed "ABCDEFG", your array will show "ABCDE" (exactly 5 characters).  If you typed a newline after each character ... you'll get 3 characters ... and 2 newlines :)

Comment: and `sizeof` result [must be printed using `%zu`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/940087/995714) or you'll get undefined behavior

Comment: @phuclv It prints the samething. Can you please explain ,which type of undefined behaviour it will show.

Comment: @prve17 UB means anything can happen. If you're lucky then it works. But in other cases like on some 64-bit platforms if the parameters were passed on stack then maybe only 4 bytes were popped out of the stack and ruin the whole program [What happens when I use the wrong format specifier?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16864552/995714)