# Why the result are so strange

Tags: c, cdecl

```
int main( )
{
   int x = 5;
   float y = 3.1f;
   printf("int x=%d   ,float x=%f    ,y=%f,    y=%d\n", x, x, y, y);  //X86
   return 0;
}
```

I think the answer are 5 , 5.0 , 3.1 , 3.
but the answer is
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h5QE5.png)

why?

Comment: Please include the output in your question as text, formatted as code, not as a link to an image on another site. And you forgot the required `#include <stdio.h>`.

Comment: To get the desired output, you need casts to the types that the corresponding format specifiers expect: `printf("int x=%d, float x=%f, y=%f, y=%d\n", x, (double)x, y, (int)y);`  Note the promotion of `float` to `double` for the fourth argument (`y`) is automatic.

Comment: [What happens when I use the wrong format specifier?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16864552/995714) UB happens

Answer (score 2):

The `%d` format specifier requires an argument of type `int`, and `%f` requires an argument of type `double` (possibly promoted from `float`).  If you pass an argument of the wrong type, the behavior is undefined.

The solution: Don't do that.

(The most likely behavior is that the memory or register containing an `int` value will be displayed *as if* it were of type `double`, but anything could happen.)

For most function calls, passing an `int` to a function expecting a `double` argument causes the value to be converted, so `42` becomes `42.0`. But since `printf` is *variadic*, the expected types are determined by the format string, not the parameter type, so the compiler can't in general know to generate a type conversion.

Comment: On platforms like x86-64 where floating point args are passed in a separate set of registers than integers, you will get a floating-point value that is totally unrelated to the integers you passed.