# What determines the data type of a variable- the declarative keyword (short int) or the format specifier (%hd)?

Tags: c, integer, integer-overflow

I have been trying to understand the integer overflow in C-programming. I am confused about whether the final value output depends on the initial datatype given to the variable during declaration or the format specifier used to print the variable.

`

```
int main() {
    short int a = 32771;
    printf("%d\n", a); // O/P : -32765
    printf("%u\n\n", a); // O/P : 4294934531

    int b = 32771;
    printf("%hd\n", b); // O/P : -32765
    printf("%hu", b); // o/p : 32771

    return 0;
}
```

`

**a** is declared a short-integer at the very start, but initialized with a value that overflows a short-integer range. The **printf("%d\n", a)** statement gives output considering **a** as a signed short-integer (2 byte or 16 bits), whereas the **printf("%u\n\n", a)** statement gives output considering it as an unsigned integer (4 bytes or 32 bits)

**b** is declared a integer (4 bytes or 32 bits) at the very start, and initialized with a value well within the integer range. The **printf("%hd\n", b)** statement gives output considering **b** as a signed short-integer (2 byte or 16 bits), whereas the **printf("%hu", b)** statement gives output considering it as an unsigned short-integer.

Please explain this discrepancy. What exactly determines the final output value?

Comment: Vararg functions like `printf` really have no idea of the actual type passed to it. That's why you need something like the format code that `printf` uses to extract the argument in the specified type. Mismatching format specifier and argument type leads to *undefined behavior*.

Comment: Your `short int` variable is converted to `int` when passed to `printf`.  So `%u` is incorrect.  You should use `%d`.  Or you can cast it to `unsigned int` when passing it to `printf`, then use `%u`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What happens when I use the wrong format specifier?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16864552/what-happens-when-i-use-the-wrong-format-specifier)

Answer (score 0):

> `short int a = 32771;`

In an initialization, the initial value, 32,771, is converted to the type of the object being initialized, `short int`, per C 2018 6.7.9 11 (paragraph 11 of clause 6.7.9 of the 2018 C standard) and 6.5.16 2.

In your C implementation, `short int` is 16 bits and can represent values from −32,768 to +32,767. So it cannot represent 32,771. When a value of integer type is converted to a signed integer type and cannot be represented in the new type, the result is implementation-defined or an implementation-defined signal is raised, per 6.3.1.3 3. This means the C implementation is required to document what it does for this. A common behavior is to wrap the result modulo 2<sup>16</sup>, so the result is 32,771 − 65,536 = −32,765.

> `printf("%d\n", a);`

`printf` is declared with `...` for arguments after its first. In such a call, the *default argument promotions* are performed on the trailing arguments, per 6.5.2.2 6. These promotions promote a `short int` to an `int`. The `%d` in the format string tells `printf` to expect an `int`, so it gets that `int`, −32,765, and prints it.

> `printf("%u\n\n", a);`

Again `a` is promoted to `int`. However, `%u` tells `printf` to expect an `unsigned int`. When the types do not match, the behavior is not defined by the C standard, per 7.21.6.3 2 and 7.21.6.1 9. However, it is common that `printf` will reinterpret the bits of an `int` as a representation of an `unsigned int`, which is 32 bits in your C implementation. When a C implementation uses two’s complement, the bits that represent −32,765 in a 32-bit `int` are FFFF8003<sub>16</sub>. Interpreted as an `unsigned int`, these bits represent 4,294,934,531, so that is what is printed.

> `printf("%hd\n", b);`

`%hd` tells `printf` to expect an `int` but to convert its value to `short int` before printing, per 7.21.6.1 7. So the conversion of 32,7761 to `short int` produces −32,765, and that is what is printed.

> `printf("%hu", b);`

`%hu` tells `printf` to expect an `int` but to convert its value to `unsigned short int` before printing, per 7.21.6.1 7. (This can vary in other C implementations; `printf` will expect whatever type an `unsigned short int` is promoted to by the *integer promotions* in 6.3.1.1 2, which is `int` in your C implementation but could be `unsigned int`.) Since 32,771 can be represented in `unsigned short int`, the conversion does not change the value, and that is what is printed.

Answer (score -4):

The type of the variable is determines when you create it.

What append is when `printf()` pars the `const char * format` he find `%u` in the string.

That say to him, he need to print a `unsigned int`, and he gonna read it with a `va_arg()` call. ([see man](https://linux.die.net/man/3/va_arg))

And he print the `unsigned int` he create, with a `write()` call.

Just for info :

> An overflow condition may give results leading to unintended behavior. In particular, if the possibility has not been anticipated, overflow can compromise a program's reliability and security.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_overflow)

If you want to dig more about bits and overflow you can print bits :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdint.h>

void print_bits(short int x)
{
        printf("%d : \n", x);
        for (int16_t i = sizeof(x) * 8 - 1 ; i >= 0; i--)
        {
                printf("%d", (x >> i) & 1);
                if (i % 8 == 0)
                        printf(" ");
        }
        printf("\n");
}

int main(void)
{
        short int a = 32767;
        print_bits(a);
        a++;
        print_bits(a);
        return (0);
}
```

That give us something like that :

```
➜ RTFM ./a.out
32767 :
01111111 11111111
-32768 :
10000000 00000000
```